# reference to variable or parameter 'DataType' must evaluate to a node list

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I had the following definition for a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="DataType" select="@DataType"/>
```

Which works just fine...

Now I want to set its value using a condition like this

```
<xsl:variable name="DataTypeOverrideType" select="$DataSource/@DataTypeOverrideType"/>
<xsl:variable name="DataType">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$ObeyTypeOverride and $DataTypeOverride = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="$DataTypeOverrideType"/>  
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="@DataType"/>      
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

But i;m getting the following error :

**reference to variable or parameter 'DataType' must evaluate to a node list**

I also tried the simplest example, like this

```
<xsl:variable name="DataType">
    <xsl:value-of select="@DataType"/>      
</xsl:variable>
```

but I keep on getting the error :|

After the changes i did to the way of defining the variable i'm trying to use it , like this

```
<xsl:when test="$DataType = 'ReachEdit'">
```

and like this

```
<xsl:when test="$DataType = 9">
```

any ideas on how can i solve this issue?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Good question (but still you may provide more data), +1. Seems like you want to have conditional selection between two nodes -- this can be accomplished with a single XPath expression and without using any XSLT conditional instructions.

Comment: Thanks, used the suggested XPath functions , string($DataType) = 'ReachEdit' and number($DataType) = 9, and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This isuue is due to the fact that you define a variable having an RTF (Result-Tree-Fragment) type**. In order to use the contents of this variable as a regular tree, you must first convert it to a regular tree using an `xxx:node-set()` extension function, where the prefix `"xxx:"` must be bound to an implementation (vendor-provided) namespace.

**Also, the provided code snippet doesn't make sense**:

```
<xsl:variable name="DataType"> 
    <xsl:choose> 
        <xsl:when test="$ObeyTypeOverride and $DataTypeOverride = 1"> 
            <xsl:value-of select="@DataType"/>   
        </xsl:when> 
        <xsl:otherwise> 
            <xsl:value-of select="@DataType"/>       
        </xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:variable>
```

In both cases above the same value is output!

**My guess is that you want something like this**:

```
<xsl:variable name="DataType"> 
    <xsl:choose> 
        <xsl:when test="$ObeyTypeOverride and $DataTypeOverride = 1"> 
            <xsl:value-of select="@DataType1"/>   
        </xsl:when> 
        <xsl:otherwise> 
            <xsl:value-of select="@DataType2"/>       
        </xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:variable>
```

**In such a case it is possible in XPath 1.0 to define the variable without creating an RTF**:

```
<xsl:variable name="DataType" select=
  "@DataType1[$ObeyTypeOverride and $DataTypeOverride = 1]
  |
   @DataType2[not($ObeyTypeOverride and $DataTypeOverride = 1)]
" />
```

**Update**: The question is now updated with corrected snippet and example of the actual uses of the variable, that cause the error message.

As the variable is used as atomic value, the error message shouldn't be raised if the following XPath expressions are used:

```
string($DataType) = 'ReachEdit'
```

and

```
number($DataType) = 9
```

Comment: I re-edited the question... hope it will be more clear now, Tx

Comment: @Daniel: OK, you can use in the comparison just: `string($DataType) = 'ReachEdit'`  , and accordingly:  `number($DataType) = 9`

Comment: I prefer not to go over the entire XSL and change all the references to the $DataType cause there are lots of... all I needed to do is to set teh value into the DataType variable conditionally, till now it was set like this :<xsl:variable name="DataType" select="@DataType"/>  and all the later refernces to $DataType were working perfectly...

Comment: @Daniel: In case if you provide a *complete* (but as small as possible) example, that we can reproduce, then I and many other people will give you a good solution. The problem seems to be in the code that you haven't shown to us.

Comment: @Daniel: How is `$ObeyTypeOverride` defined?

Comment: <xsl:variable name="ObeyTypeOverride" select="@ObeyTypeOverride = '1'"/>

Comment: thanks allot for the help.. eventually i sued the Xpath functions string number, and it works

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't think you get the error message "reference to variable or parameter ... must evaluate to a node list" for the code snippet you posted as setting up a variable as you do is possible. However the variable then is a result tree fragment with a single text child node, not a node set. So I suspect later on you try something like `<xsl:apply-templates select="$DataType"/>` or `<xsl:for-each select="$DataType">...</xsl:for-each>` and then you get the error.

It is difficult to suggest a solution as your snippet

```
<xsl:variable name="DataType">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$ObeyTypeOverride and $DataTypeOverride = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="@DataType"/>  
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="@DataType"/>      
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

logically does not make much sense to me, both the `when` and the `otherwise` do `value-of select="@DataType"` so I wonder what it really is you want to achieve, other than directly doing `<xsl:variable name="DataType" select="@DataType"/>`.

So you will need to explain in more detail what you want to achieve, then we can suggest an XSLT way of solving that.

[edit]
Perhaps
`<xsl:variable name="DataType" select="($DataSource/@DataTypeOverrideType[$ObeyTypeOverride and . = 1] | @DataType)[1]"/>` suffices.

Comment: both the when and the otherwise where the same only for the example... i edited the question... and showed the later usage i;m doing with $DataType

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the right place of the error.. (the later usage of the variable)